# calling atexit function within a class constructor

Tags: c++

I want to use std::atexit function within the class for cleanup on abnormal termination.
I am registering function handle within the class constructor but getting an error. (codetest.cpp:12:25: error: invalid use of non-static member function)
here is my simple code for understanding (other it is a big project where application exit on some fatal error but I need to cleanup some attribute of mu class)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

class cleanUP
{
public:
    cleanUP ()
    {
        atexit (atexit_handler);
    }
    ~cleanUP()
    {

    }

    void atexit_handler ()
    {
        // Will cleanup some temp files and malloc things.
        cout << "Call atexit" <<endl;
    }
};

int main () {
  cleanUP cleanup;
}
```

is there any other good approach for cleanup.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [invalid use of non-static member function( in qt)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22749787/invalid-use-of-non-static-member-function-in-qt)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `std::atexit` can only register a true (unbound) function or a static method from a class but not a non static method.

If you do not need a pointer to the object, the simplest way would be to make the handler static:

```
static void atexit_handler ()
{
    // Will cleanup some temp files and malloc things.
    cout << "Call atexit" <<endl;
}
```

But anyway, if you create more than one object, you will register many times the same handler which is at least useless. If you really want (or need) to go that way you should:

- ensure you register the handler only once by using a static guard variable (and a mutex or other critical section if you want to be thread-safe)
- register the objects that need processing in a standard container that would be a static member of the class
- make the static handler process the registered objects

But the idiomatic way of cleanup is simply to use a destructor and to ensure that all dynamic objects are correctly deleted before the program exits.